# OnePage scroll down button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On this page:
http://www.petertoth.me/stuff/petertoth_old/www.petertoth.me/index.html
there is a scroll down button, that smoothly scrolls down to the "next page". Anyone recognizes if it's a pre-made jQuery plugin, or a modified one? I've been researching about it quite a while, found out its possible to mimic this one more or less with such approach:

```
var scrolled=0;    
$(document).ready(function(){                
    $("#downClick").on("click" ,function(){
      scrolled=scrolled+100;

      $("html, body").animate({
              scrollTop:  scrolled
         });  
    });

});
```

or

```
$('#gdb1').click(function(){
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(window).height()}, 600);
return false;});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uw1hdkaf/20/
but would be more than happy to know how to properly make it with jQuery or without it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to factor in, that the elements need to have an exact height of how much you want to scroll down. Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/uw1hdkaf/22/

```
p {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The paragraph tag has a set margin of 16px, so you need to remove that. Basically making each element completely 0 in everything.

If you set the height to 100px and scroll down 100px using your script, it will guaranteed scroll down to the next element, as long as you make sure the elements are exactly as tall as you set them.

Comment: Thanks! This is more or less what I needed, but I have troubles with incorporating it into my project :/ Should I just save JS code into for example scroll.js, include it and jquery into <head> and everything should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Alex Sure yeah. Remember to load it after the DOM has been loaded.